# Problems with table per tenant in EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement table per tenant solution using Eclipselink as ORM since Hibernate does not have "table per tenant" strategy support for now.

Although I set tenant information to EntityManager before the transaction starts, EclipseLink tries to query the other tenant's table which i have to set in application.properties file.

You could find all the project here -> `https://github.com/ercancelik/eclipselink-multitenant`

After running the project, you should execute the ddls in src/main/resources/ddl.sql file in H2 console -> `http://localhost:8080/console/login.jsp`.

After that you can run the curl command to see the error. Although I set `TENANT2` to the request headers, it tries to query `TENANT1`'s table.

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/customers -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-TenantID: TENANT2'
```